# Roslyn - Find related code symbols

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

When I have an ISymbol reference to a method that is defined in a class, is there a way to find all other related symbols in that SemanticModel? For example, fields, properties, other(private) methods that are called, etc ...
I need all other symbols that are necessary to successfully run the given method.

The intention is to keep only the code that is strictly necessary to run that method, and remove all other excessive code from the syntax tree.

Comment: Can you give a proper example of what you mean?

Comment: Also, what's the context here? An analyzer or something else?

Comment: You cannot do that with only the method symbol, you'll need to look at the source of the method. Obviously, you'll need to do that recursively: if you find your method calls another method, you'll need to analyze that other method too. Last but not least, remember you will only find code that is referenced statically. If your code uses reflection, what you want is very hard, if not impossible. Another option may be to run your method from a set of unit tests, with code coverage enabled.